# multiprocessing.Pool and slurm

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, slurm

I wrote a simple function that calculates the number of lines in a file.

```
def line_count(file_name):
    temp = 0
    with open(file_name,'r') as ref:
        ref.readline()
        for line in ref:
            temp+=1
    return temp,file_name
```

Then I use `Pool` to apply it to each file I have in a folder:

```
files=[]
for f in glob.glob(data_directory+'/*.txt'):
    files.append(f)
with Pool(np.min([tot_process,len(files)])) as pool:
    rt = pool.map(line_count,files)
```

where `tot_process` is an argument I pass from a slurm script which runs the Python code. In the slurm script, I have the following header:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=60
#SBATCH --partition=normal
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --mem=0
#SBATCH --job-name=test
```

Since the function takes about 4 seconds for a 40M-lines files, I would expect that running the code with `tot_process=60` on a folder with 60 files would take approximately the same. Instead, it takes around 240 seconds. I suspect I am missing something very basic here and my script is not running multiprocessing as it should.

Comment: This script is I/O bound... spending the vast majority of its time waiting for the file to read from disk. You can spin up a bunch of processes, but its that same disk I/O channel so you won't see a speedup.

Comment: Does it mean that basically it is not processing each file in parallel? But rather each process is waiting for another one to finish? Because I did not think about that since each processor should read a different file...

Comment: I think @tdelaney is correct. I've done something similar with nearly the exact same code as you, but the files were much smaller and did not run into this issues. I did however notice some weird behaviuor where the last process would kind of hang for a while or sometimes never actually end.. I fixed this by using `mp.set_start_method('spawn')`

Comment: @FG89 - Not quite. You have many file read requests going in parallel (one waiting per process, generally). This could potentially slow you down as the disk will likely seek more often. You make get a small uptick in performance by using a larger blocksize and opening in binary mode to avoid the bytes to string translation.

Comment: Thank you guys! Very useful thing to learn, I had no idea about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are I/O bound. No matter how many processes you create, the hard drive itself can only read the files so fast. It must seek to a file block, read at the speed of the spinning disk and repeat for as many blocks are in the file. And the disk is attached to the computer via some sort of bus - likely SATA or SCSI - and it has its own speed limitations (though likely much faster than the disk itself). An SSD drive is faster than a spinning disk but the general rule still applies.

40 million lines suggests files in the range of a gig. At 4 seconds you are getting 250 MB data transfer rate, which is quite fast (assuming a standard locally attached hard drive).

You may get some speedup by skipping multiprocessing completely and switching to a memory mapped file. Here is an example of reading in fairly large blocks with Direct I/O. I haven't profiled this, so its just a guess.

```
import os
import mmap

LINE_COUNT_BLOCKSIZE = 2**25   # 32 Meg

def line_count(filename):
    fd = os.open(filename, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_DIRECT)
    try:
        with mmap.mmap(fd, 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as mm:
            count = 0
            while True:
                buf = mm.read(LINE_COUNT_BLOCKSIZE)
                if not buf:
                    break
                count += buf.count(b"\n")
            return count
    finally:
        os.close(fd)
```